# Code keeps looping into max call stack error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make tic tac toe on a website using javascript. That worked and now I'm trying to make a bot that, then you have 2 area's in a row. It needs to block you. But everytime it does block me, it won't do anything else afterwards, because it keeps looping into the error.

The t-numbers are the tile names, 0 means unoccupied,1 means for player 1, and 2 for player 2.
The t-numbers with a 1 behind it are just the tiles but they mustn't interfere with the functions (they are t-numbers too).

How do I fix this?

```
function tbot(){
  while (turn == "player 2") {
    if (t41 == 0 &&
      (t01 == 1 && t81 == 1) ||
      (t11 == 1 && t71 == 1) ||
      (t21 == 1 && t61 == 1) ||
      (t31 == 1 && t51 == 1)
    ) {t4()}

    else {
    var tiles = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'];
    var tile = tiles[Math.floor(Math.random()*tiles.length)];
         if (tile == '0' && t01 == 0) {t0()}
    else if (tile == '1' && t11 == 0) {t1()}
    else if (tile == '2' && t21 == 0) {t2()}
    else if (tile == '3' && t31 == 0) {t3()}
    else if (tile == '4' && t41 == 0) {t4()}
    else if (tile == '5' && t51 == 0) {t5()}
    else if (tile == '6' && t61 == 0) {t6()}
    else if (tile == '7' && t71 == 0) {t7()}
    else if (tile == '8' && t81 == 0) {t8()}
  }
  }
}
```

```
function update() {
  if (t01 == 1 &&
    ((t11 == 1 && t21 == 1)||(t31 == 1 && t61 == 1))
    ||t41 == 1 &&
    ((t31 == 1 && t51 == 1)||(t11 == 1 && t71 == 1)||
    (t01 == 1 && t81 == 1)||(t21 == 1 && t61 == 1))
    ||t81 == 1 &&
    ((t61 == 1 && t71 == 1)||(t21 == 1 && t51 == 1))
) {
  twin = 1;
  document.getElementById('turnshow').innerHTML = "Player 1 is the winner!";
  document.getElementById('treset').style.backgroundColor = '#888';
  } else if (t01 == 2 &&
    ((t11 == 2 && t21 == 2)||(t31 == 2 && t61 == 2))
    ||t41 == 2 &&
    ((t31 == 2 && t51 == 2)||(t11 == 2 && t71 == 2)||
    (t01 == 2 && t81 == 2)||(t21 == 2 && t61 == 2))
    ||t81 == 2 &&
    ((t61 == 2 && t71 == 2)||(t21 == 2 && t51 == 2))
) {
  twin = 1;
  document.getElementById('turnshow').innerHTML = "Player 2 is the winner!";
  document.getElementById('treset').style.backgroundColor = '#888';
  } else {
  if (bot == 1) {tbot();}
  document.getElementById('turnshow').innerHTML = "It is " + turn + "'s turn!";
  }
}
```

```
function t4() {
  if (t41 == 0 && twin == 0) {
  if (turn == "player 1") {
    document.getElementById('t4').style.backgroundColor = p1;
    turn = "player 2";
    t41 = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('t4').style.backgroundColor = p2;
    turn = "player 1";
    t41 = 2;
  }
}
update();
}
```

Comment: What is your error? it should give a stacktrace you can follow to see what methods it's looping into.

Comment: You should learn to work with arrays. Having `t01`, `t1()`, ... all over the place makes this code practically unreadable. Avoid code repetition.

Answer (score 1):

The program never exit the while loop because condition (`turn == "player 2"`) is always true.

If you're expecting `t4()` to change `turn` then I guess it doesn't do the job right. Check for `(t41 == 0 && twin == 0)`, turn will never change if this condition is never been true.

Answer (score 0):

I found what i did wrong. When I was checking if there are two area's selected in a row my code was:

```
if (t41 == 0 &&
      (t01 == 1 && t81 == 1) ||
      (t11 == 1 && t71 == 1) ||
      (t21 == 1 && t61 == 1) ||
      (t31 == 1 && t51 == 1)
    )
```

But what that did: t41 and t01 and t81 or t11 and t71 or etc.
I just needed to add "()" around the options :/

```
if (t41 == 0 &&
      ((t01 == 1 && t81 == 1) ||
      (t11 == 1 && t71 == 1) ||
      (t21 == 1 && t61 == 1) ||
      (t31 == 1 && t51 == 1))
    )
```